# capture web data using scrapy regular expression

Tags: regex, scrapy

I tried to capture an URL in the source code of http://uslpro.uslsoccer.com/teams/2014/22310.html#ROSTER.

Part of the source code is shown as below.

```
getPlayers: function(){
    var url;
    $j('.visibleDiv').hide().removeClass('visibleDiv');
    $j('span#indicator-text').text('Roster');
    $j('div#indicator').fadeIn();
    url = '/teams/65672455/22310-65672522-ros.js';
```

The url is what I want to capture. I used regular expression

```
pattern = re.escape("$j('div#indicator').fadeIn();") + '\s*url\s*=\s*(.*);'
```

but it is not working. I tried this regular expression in JavaScript. It can locate at the beginning index.

Could someone kindly help me with this regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the [`re.DOTALL` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: t = """getPlayers: function(){
    var url;
    $j('.visibleDiv').hide().removeClass('visibleDiv');
    $j('span#indicator-text').text('Roster');
    $j('div#indicator').fadeIn();
    url = '/teams/65672455/22310-65672522-ros.js';   """

In [3]: pattern = re.escape("$j('div#indicator').fadeIn();") + '\s*url\s*=\s*(.*);'

In [4]: re.search(pattern, t, re.DOTALL).groups()
Out[4]: ("'/teams/65672455/22310-65672522-ros.js'",)

In [5]:
```

Comment: I think without re.DOTALL, just re.search(pattern, t).groups() is also working. I used scrapy's response.selector.re(pattern), it did not work when I posted, but I just tried, it works now. Thank you all the same.